# include role if variable is true

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want a role to be included in my Ansible playbook if a variable value is true and not executed if it is false. I thought this should work but the integration test gets run even if `run_integration_test` is `false`

```yaml
- include_role:
    name: integration_test
    when: "{{ run_integration_test }}"
  tags:
  - configure_integration
  - aws
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You have some pretty severe indentation problems in that example. Is that what the actual code looks like?

Comment: Sorry, just edited it. That's how it looks. All except `when: "{{ run_integration_test }}"` was already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an indentation problem: `when` is a task option, not an argument to `include_role`. You need to write:

```
- include_role:
    name: integration_test
  when: run_integration_test
  tags:
  - configure_integration
  - aws
```

Notice that `when` is aligned with `tags` in this example.

---

There's a trap here you might hit depending on how you're setting `run_integration_test`. You might try running something like this:

```
ansible-playbook -e run_integration_test=false ...
```

And you would be surprised that the task still runs. In the above command line, we're setting `run_integration_test` to the string value "false" rather than to boolean `false`, and a non-empty string evaluates to `true`. One way to deal with this is to write your `when` expression like this:

```
when: "run_integration_test|default(false)|bool"
```

This will (a) default to `false` if `run_integration_test` is unsent, and (b) will cast string values "true" and "false" to the correct boolean value using the `bool` filter.

Comment: I changed the indentation but my test still runs. Do I need to have anything like `when: "{{ run_integration_test }} == true"`? I assume not but worth asking.

Comment: See my update, which may be relevant to your question. If that doesn't help, let me know exactly how you're setting the variable.

Comment: Actually, one more edit: you don't use Jinja template markers (`{{...}}`) in a `when` expression; it's implicitly evaluated inside a template context. You should get a warning from ansible about that.